# Why can't I describe Simulink.MSFcnRunTimeBlock

Tags: matlab, oop, rtti

Despite the fact, that `Simulink.MSFcnRunTimeBlock` is a class with a lot of members, the command `?` returns empty matrix:

```
>> ?Simulink.MSFcnRunTimeBlock

ans = 

  0x0 class array with properties:

    Name
    Description
    DetailedDescription
    Hidden
    Sealed
    Abstract
    ConstructOnLoad
    HandleCompatible
    InferiorClasses
    ContainingPackage
    PropertyList
    MethodList
    EventList
    EnumerationMemberList
    SuperclassList
```

**UPDATE**

```
properties Simulink.MSFcnRunTimeBlock
```

also returns "No properties for class Simulink.MSFcnRunTimeBlock or no class Simulink.MSFcnRunTimeBlock." despite the fact this class has [`AllowSignalsWithMoreThan2D`, `DialogPrmsTunable` and `NextTimeHit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.msfcnruntimeblock.html#brhzkau-1) properties according to docs.

Why?